# How to include parent fields into $project when aggregating embbeded

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
offers: [],
```

});

```
var OfferSchema = new Schema({
dateFrom: Date,
dateTill: Date,
destination: String,
budget: String,
currency: {},
dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

});

I make an aggregations:

```
            User.aggregate(
            { $project: {"offers": 1, _id: 0}},
            { $unwind: "$offers" },
            { $sort: {"offers.dateCreated": -1} },
            function (err, result) {
                if (!err) {

            }
        );
```

And the result is ok, but I want every element to include its parent fields (ex: _id and other fields).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **$project** stage:

```
User.aggregate(
        { $unwind: "$offers" },
        { $sort: {"offers.dateCreated": -1} },
        function (err, result) {
            if (!err) {

        }
    );
```